# Does Visual Studio 2015 GIT use 3-way merge?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

When I use Visual Studio 2015's merge tool to fix conflicts, it seems like it is performing worse than when I use P4Merge with GIT's command line (which finds almost no conflicts at all).

Is this because of the tool itself? Does Visual Studio 2015's merge/diff tool provide 3-way merge for GIT?

Comment: Yes.  Providing some context, like the hunks that it's having trouble with that P4Merge gets right, may provide some elucidation to your problem.  (Perhaps it's a line ending issue.)  Or perhaps P4Merge is just better than Visual Studio's.

Comment: Well I am really just looking for a source somewhere on the web that can confirm my assumption (what kind of merge Visual Studio does when using GIT). I haven't been able to find that.

Comment: It is a three-way merge...  that's really the only kind of merge there is!

Comment: No, TFS will do a 2 way merge as far as I have understood. Try Googling it. That is why GIT typically has far less conflicts than TFS.

Comment: First the question is about Git, not TFVC.  Second that's still incorrect about TFVC, regardless of what the Internet might have said.  You can get TFVC to do a three way merge with an empty virtual ancestor, but to call that a "two way merge" is not really a definition that anybody would use.  But again, that has no bearing on Git in Visual Studio.

Comment: Further you're talking about the conflict resolution tools (VS or P4Merge) that kick in when you _have_ a conflict.  These tools are independent of the version control system that created them.

Comment: Aha, I see. Thanks for clearing that up. Put that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I'd be happy to - but I am still curious why Visual Studio's merge tool and P4Merge show such different results.  I would have thought that they would at least be close, so I'm curious if VS is legitimately bad or if there's something more subtle going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Visual Studio does three-way merges, both when merging your Git repository and when trying to resolve the conflicts that arise.  It's not immediately clear why VS would be inferior to P4Merge while resolving that conflict, but without knowing anything else, I suspect that P4Merge is better about [inconsistent line ending configurations](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).

There are two stages to the merge process:  first, performing the merge and producing a combined tree that includes new changes from both branches and (possibly) conflicts, and second, a conflict resolution stage.

In Visual Studio, the first stage is a regular git merge, which is indeed a three way merge.  The "merge base" is found, which is the last commit that exists in both branches; this is the last time your two branches were merged, or the point at which one branch was created from the other.

Then a three way merge is performed at the tree level by determining which files have changed in each branch, comparing them to the common ancestor.  If a file has changed in *one* branch, then that branch's changes will be included in the new tree.  If a file has changed in *both* branches, then we need to do a three way merge at the *file* level, which is very similar and compares the files in each branch to their common ancestor.  Now, if any region of the file has changed in *one* branch, relative to the common ancestor, then we'll include that changed region in the merged file.  But if both branches have changed the same region, then a conflict will be produced.

Git will produce a file in the working directory with conflict markers, but it will also record the two files and their common ancestor so that you can use a merge tool (like Visual Studio or P4Merge).

(Note that when you perform a merge using Visual Studio, it uses the [libgit2](http://www.libgit2.org/) library, though [it produces the same results](http://githubengineering.com/move-fast/) as Git itself.)

Once you have a merge conflict, your merge tool can take the three files and provide you a graphical experience to resolve the conflicts.  Typically, the first step in each of these tools is to try to do the file-level merge again, and will create a new "result" file (often shown in the middle pane of three panes, with the two branches on either side, or less commonly above or below the two branch files).

This result will typically include any regions that were not overlapping automatically merged in, and the UI will generally prompt you to resolve the overlapping regions that couldn't be automerged.  Generally speaking, my experience is that there isn't *a lot* of difference here, but certainly there could be variations.  In particular:

- Some tools may be more aggressive about joining small conflicts that are near to each other together, which may give fewer but larger conflicts that may be easier to resolve - for example, if you had several conflicts that were one-line each it may be preferable to squash those into a single, larger conflict.
- Some tools may do encoding translations, so that you can correctly merge a file that was UTF-8 in the common ancestor, UTF-16 in one branch and Latin1 in the other branch and get an intelligent output in one of those encodings (or even a different one altogether).
- Some tools may elide whitespace changes.  I have a hunch that this might be where you're seeing differences between Visual Studio and P4Merge; line ending configuration is notoriously difficult to setup across an entire team in Windows Git clients.  A merge tool that simply ignored line ending differences could produce a *much* nicer experience than one that did not.

You *could* even use a tool that understood the structure of your document:  for example, merging two XML files typically doesn't try to understand the structure of the XML, but [you *could* use a tool that understood XML](http://www.altova.com/diffdog.html) to avoid things like whitespace changes that don't actually matter to the meaning of the file.

Comment: Out of curiousity, does TFS also use 3-way merge?

Comment: @Mathias It does for branches you can merge directly (eg, those that have a parent/child relationship).  But if you try to merge from a grandchild branch then it will not have recorded a merge base, so it will do a "baseless" merge, which is a three way merge with an empty base and is basically useless.

Comment: It's so strange how TFS can give a gazillion more conflicts than GIT then. Any idea on that?

Comment: Do you have auto merge enabled?  Prior versions of TFVC did not even attempt an automerge, so you would have to click the "automerge all" button when the conflicts page showed.  (Newer versions _will_ do this by default.)

Comment: It's also possible that it's just not very good with conflicts.  :P

Comment: But how can that be? I thought merging algorithms were well known and documented. If one works really well, why would they deliberately choose abad algorithm for merging?

Comment: I just learned about merge tracking. Could this be the reason TFS is horrible at merges compared to GIT?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen If by "merge tracking", you mean remembering the most recent merge to use as a merge base, then of course TFS does this.  I don't know that TFS _is_ horrible at merges compared to Git, but if you provide a minimum viable example, then that would be helpful to discuss what's actually going on.