# Is the default merge tool in TFS 2012 three-way or two-way?

Tags: git, tfs, merge, version-control, tfvc

We are using Team Foundation Server - TFS 2012 and have TFVC set as the version control. I would like to know whether the default merge tool uses a three-way, or a two-way merging method?

If it uses a three-way method then how different is it from the merging used in Git ?

Comment: Perhaps have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889599/does-visual-studio-2015-git-use-3-way-merge

Comment: Yes I checked that article but some of the answers there are conflicting, not clear whether it actually uses a 2-way or 3-way merge for TFVC as version control in tfs 2012.

Comment: You could consider the answers from Edward Thompson the good one as he was the Product manager of Git inside TFS at the time of the answer. So the probability of a better answer is very low....